# Javascript validating a text area to find a SSN

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a quick validation of a text area notes field to see if it potentially contains a SSN number which I will then throw an alert for.

I have tried a few different RegEx patters I have found online and none of them seem to be working. I am wondering if its my javascript that isn't correct?

I believe if it were to find a match, it would be true thus throw the `SSN Found` alert.

Anyone point out my mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="submit"]').click(function() {
    validate();
  })
})

// Validate our note field
function validate() {

  var isValid = true,
    notes = $('[name=notes]').val(),
    ssn = new RegExp('^(?!219-09-9999|078-05-1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4}$');

    console.log(notes)

  if (ssn.test(notes)) {
    alert('SSN Found');
  }else{
    alert('No SSN Found');
  }

}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sgrw4rqf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your regex global rather than matching the SSN only.

Use something like this:

```
if ($('[name=notes]').val().match(/\b(?!219-09-9999|078-05-1120)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4}\b/g)) {
```

and it will match as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now. I got the validation from here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651609/Validating-Social-Security-Numbers-through-Regular

Comment: Updating my answer to address the edge case rules that I did not know about.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Basically, ^ means "start of string" and $ means "end of string" so you just needed to remove those and make your search global.

Comment: This will also match e.g. `56789123-45-67891234`.